# how to send an array as post request in REST using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, rest, post

Here is my code,

```
$ip = array([0]=>'1.1.1.1' [1]=> '2.2.2.2')

$ux = RestClient::post($url,array('requestType'=>'Ip', 
                                                     'username' => 'user', 
                                                             'pass' =>'user',
                        'type'=>$type,
                        'ip'=>array($ip)                            
                            ));
  echo $ux->getResponse();
```

How to post 'ip' at server side? When I use $_POST['id'], it returns 'Array' as string.

Comment: what about, convert the array info json?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't post an array. You have to serialize it to a string.
That could be the standard form encoding method:

```
ip=1.1.1.1&ip=2.2.2.2
```

That could be JSON:

```
{ "ip" : [ "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ] }
```

That could be some XML format:

```
<ips>
    <ip>1.1.1.1</ip>
    <ip>2.2.2.2</ip>
</ips>
```

That could be something else.

… but what you need to do depends on what the API you are submitting to expects.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ip[]=1.1.1.1&ip[]=2.2.2.2`? (Note the brackets)

Comment: @fireeyedboy — No. That's a peculiarity of PHP's form parsing routines. Here PHP is the client, the server is unspecified.

Comment: Ah right, I wasn't sure about how other platforms deal with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to use JSON for your array. Convert it with `json_encode( $array )`